# Message function in R not writing to text file / print message to stdout

Tags: r, console, sink

I'm writing some text to R console using `print(), cat() and message()` functions. I wish to collect console outputs into a text file, so I sandwiched the code between a pair of `sink()` functions. Final code looks like:

```
sink("output_filename.txt") 
print("some text with print function")
cat("some text with cat function")
message("some text with message function")
sink()
```

When I run this code, print and cat work as expected while `message's output writes to console` and not output text file. Why does this happen and how do I work around this? I prefer not to replace message function with alternatives.

Comment: Why don't you store it as `Rmd` and render to get same result, but with messages?

Comment: `message()` sends to *stderr*, `print()` and `cat()` to *stdout* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like [jogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414452/jogo) already mentioned in the commentary, `message()` sends to stdeer, instead of `stdout`. You can change this by using `sink(stdout(), type = "message")`

```
sink("output_filename.txt") 
sink(stdout(), type = "message")
print("some text with print function")
cat("some text with cat function\n")
message("some text with message function")
sink()
```

from [documentary](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/sink) of `sink()`:

> Normal R output (to connection stdout) is diverted by the default type
>   = "output". Only prompts and (most) messages continue to appear on the console. Messages sent to stderr() (including those from message,
>   warning and stop) can be diverted by sink(type = "message") (see
>   below).

also you might change it back after you are done, since warnings and stops are also changed to `stdout` this way